# How to use underscore.js reduce method?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

anyone got any examples on how to use the reduce method in underscore.

Answer (score 19):

Here are two javascript examples, quite similar to underscore.

These find the mathematical mean and the standard deviation in an array of numbers.

You often see reduce working with thousands or millions of items in  arrays related to populatons or statistics.

```
Math.mean= function(array){
    return array.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})/array.length;
}
Math.stDeviation= function(array){
    var mean= Math.mean(array),
    dev= array.map(function(itm){return (itm-mean)*(itm-mean);});
    return Math.sqrt(dev.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})/array.length);
}

var A2= [6.2, 5, 4.5, 6, 6, 6.9, 6.4, 7.5];
alert ('mean: '+Math.mean(A2)+'; deviation: '+Math.stDeviation(A2))

/*  returned value: (String)
mean: 6.0625; deviation: 0.899913190257816
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

They have it... http://underscorejs.org/#reduce
Right there - at the official Underscore.js site.